# Can't delete a programmatically created calendar from the user interface

Tags: ios, calendar, icalendar

Yes, I have messed with creating calendars, and I could delete all the instances created but one. I just can't delete it from the user interface, I can edit ti but pressing "delete Calendar" has no effect and no warning.

What can I do? It doesn't really matter as I am on my development device, but really I'd like to get to the bottom of this as it could have an impact on the final app.

Answer (score 5):

Found the problem. For some reason that I haven't been able to explain yet, the calendar was shared with the Reminders app. Odd, I don't know how it happened ( it didn't for the rest of the calendars I created...).

So all is well now, once I deleted the calendar from the reminder app, then I could delete it in the calendar app itself.

Very wrong that there is no alert that the calendar is shared and therefore can not be deleted... seems like a miss